# как вввести число и столько же раз можно было ввести имён и потом их вывести?

Tags: java, scanner

```
пример ввода в консоли
3
Athos
Porthos
Aramis

Вывод в консоли:

Hello, Athos
Hello, Porthos
Hello, Aramis
```

А пример кода, приведенный выше, к сожалению, в таком виде не выводит информацию.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.
Вот пишу код

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloStrangers {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Write a program, asks for a number - amount of strangers to meet.
        //Then reads stranger names line by line and prints line by line "Hello, ...".
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = scan.nextInt();
        if (number > 0) {
            String[] word = new String[number];
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                word[i] = scan.nextLine();
            }
            for (i = 0; i < number+1; i++) {
                System.out.println("Hello, " + word[i]);
            }
        }
        else if (number ==0 )
        { System.out.println("Oh, it looks like there is no one here");
        }
        else  {
            System.out.println("Seriously? Why so negative?");
        }
        
    }

    }
```

Что за throws IOException? До исключений в java еще не добрался))) Не судите строго))

Comment: 1) Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь. 2) Доберитесь до исключений, разберитесь, спросите, что конкретно непонятно. Это и есть обучение.

Comment: Благодарю Вас. Ответ на свой вопрос я получил от специалиста had0uken. Смотрите ниже. Но ваши пожелания и уточнения обязательно учту.))

Comment: А мне-то зачем смотеть?:-) Нашелся кто-то, коме не лень было смотреть неполный запрос, ну и хорошо. Чаще не находятся.

Comment: Пока разбираюсь. Это мое первое сообщение на данной платформе было)) Буду учиться!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поправил вашу программу в 2ух местах: Ошибки пометил в коде с помощью слешей **///////**

1 ошибка)  вы вычитываете целое число сканером, а потом нажимаете Enter, который передает символ **\n** - переход на новую строку, который в итоге записывается в ваш массив **words** под 0 индексом. Обойти данную проблему можно добавим строку **scan.nextLine();** она "съест" лишний **\n**. И тогда вы будете в ваш массив уже записывать непосредственно имена.

2 ошибка ) в последнем for цикле выходите за пределы массива и получаете исключение. - Так же поправил.

По поводу исключений, в данной программе они вам не нужны. Поэтому убрал throws IOException. - Разберетесь в них когда дойдете до этой темы. Пока можете не вдаваться в подробности. Тема достаточно обширная чтобы одним ответом объяснить обработку исключений. Это целый раздел.

```
public class HelloStrangers {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        //Write a program, asks for a number - amount of strangers to meet.
        //Then reads stranger names line by line and prints line by line "Hello, ...".
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();///////
        if (number > 0) {
            String[] word = new String[number];
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                word[i] = scan.nextLine();
            }
            for (i = 0; i < number; i++) { ///////
                System.out.println("Hello, " + word[i]);
            }
        }
        else if (number ==0 )
        { System.out.println("Oh, it looks like there is no one here");
        }
        else  {
            System.out.println("Seriously? Why so negative?");
        }

    }

}
```

Консоль

```
3
Athos
Porthos
Aramis
Hello, Athos
Hello, Porthos
Hello, Aramis

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас! Вы мне очень помогли!)) А то учусь сам и этой особенности (передает символ \n - переход на новую строку, который в итоге записывается в ваш массив) откровенно говоря не знал. Вот и завис на этом вопросе. А сейчас буду понимать о чем речь. Еще раз благодарю Вас.